# Mechanize and BeautifulSoup for PHP?

Tags: php, python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I was wondering if there was anything similar like Mechanize or BeautifulSoup for PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SimpleTest provides you with similar functionality:

http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html

Comment: SimpleTest Browser class indeed does seem to do the job right however I was looking for something lighter, perhaps some library not oriented for Unit Testing?

Comment: You can use SimpleTest's browser without the rest of the framework. It's a self-contained subcomponent.

Comment: require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/simpletest.php'); and a dozen of other includes.

Comment: And that site appears to now be dead

Comment: You can try this php package https://github.com/amsify42/php-domfinder

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how powerful BeautifulSoup is, so maybe this won't be as great ; but you could try using [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) :

> The function parses the HTML contained
>   in the string source . Unlike loading
>   XML, HTML does not have to be
>   well-formed to load.

After using this, you should be able to access the HTML document using DOM methods -- including XPath queries.

Comment: +1 for the native suggestion, although doing XPath queries is several times more complex than doing the same thing in BeautifulSoup.